# Font problem when editing TeX produced pdf in external software

Tags: fonts, pdf, inkscape

When I try to import TeX/LaTeX produced pdf code in Inkscape, then I loose a lot of the interletter and interword spacing, almost all interword spacing is shown wrong, the exponents are not at their normal place, glyphs interlap and so on.  Is there anything in the pdf code that TeX produces that can cause that strange behaviour?  I use pdftex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Sounds like an Inkscape problem. Can you make a minimal pdf available somewhere for testing?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to import TeX generated pdf into Inkscape?

Comment: According to the Inkscape FAQ, it should support pdf natively. However in earlier versions they used some kind of converter. What version are you using and what operating systems? Although they should be fully compatible, the implementation might differ a little.

Comment: I've experienced issues with spacing in inkscape generally - it doesn't normally make outlines unless you tell it to, but the letter spacing can go wrong quite easily.  If you import a .pdf from origin or a .pdf or even a .svg from matplotlib (check font settings) then change the font size by dialog box you will see that the spacing doesn't scale appropriately - letters overlap etc.  It may have more work to do on TeX output but I think text is one of the things inkscape doesn't do so well.

Comment: @IanThompson you could easily want to take and equation or a tikz figure for example and put it in a piece of work that's not well-suited to TeX.  Inkscape may be a final step (it's what I use for posters) or an intermediate step.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check if inkscape can access the font used by pdftex.
2. Try a lower version of pdf (pdftex command \pdfminorversion ).
3. See what happens when you convert .pdf to .svg with gsview (menu edit--convert to vector format) or get pstoedit and say `pstoedit -f plot-svg <input-file> <output-file>` (from [inkscape wiki](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Current_PDF_Support#PDF_Import)).

Comment: I had the same issue. I found `pdf2svg`to work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem may be that Inkscape currently imports text from PDF "as text", replacing fonts by fonts available to inkscape.

If this is the origin of your problem, one approach can be to install Latex fonts for Inkscape. You can follow instructions on http://typethinker.blogspot.fr/2008/06/integrating-inkscape-graphics-in-latex.html.